# How can I trace Grails dependencies of dependencies?

Tags: grails, dependencies

My Grails Project, though running fine from within IntelliJ fails to build via command line or in Jenkins, reporting a dependency issue with a dependency **not** listed in my BuildConfig.xml.

Issue:

```
Error Plugin release-3.0.0 requires version [2.3 > *] of Grails which your current Grails installation does not meet. Please try install a different version of the plugin or Grails.
```

Dependencies in BuildConfig.xml:

```
plugins {
        compile(":csv:0.3.1")
        compile ":executor:0.3"
        compile ":audit-logging:0.5.4"
        compile ':ckeditor:3.6.2.1'
        build ':codenarc:0.17'
        runtime ":database-migration:1.1"
        compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"
        compile ":filterpane:2.0.1.1"
        compile ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        compile ":jquery:1.7.2"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.15"
        compile ":jquery-ui-timepicker:0.9.8.1"
        compile ":mail:1.0"
        compile ":resources:1.1.6"
        compile ":rest:0.7"
        test ":spock:0.6"
        test ':code-coverage:1.2.5'
        compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'
        compile ':spring-security-ui:0.2'
        compile ":taggable:1.0.1"
        compile ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
        compile ':enhanced-scaffolding:1.0.RC2'
        compile ':build-test-data:2.0.2'
        compile ':jslint:0.5'
    }
    dependencies {
        runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc3'
        compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.10'
        compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.7'
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.5.2'
        compile 'org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:0.12'
        compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1'
        runtime 'owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:r99'
        compile 'com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3'
        test 'org.objenesis:objenesis:1.2'
    }
```

Can anyone recommend a way to trace which plugin or dependency causes the missing error?

TIA,

pit

Comment: I guess you have different versions on grails,When running from IntelliJ it use grails version 2.3 > *.

But when running from command line it use old version (to check it open command line and type grails -version ).

Comment: No, the Grails versions is 2.0.4 in both instances, it is output verbosely while compiling or running both on cmdline as in IJ's console.

Comment: theory: one of the plugins mentioned in BuildConfig.groovy seems to have a export=true dependency on the release plugin without providing a valid version range. Do a `grep -sirn ":release" ~/.grails/<version>/<project>`

Comment: Thanks Stefan. This seems to be the the culprit: 
/plugins/modernizr-1.7.2/dependencies.groovy:29:  build(**':release:latest.integration'**)

How can I override that dependency? I have no Ivy/Mvn experience at all.

Comment: grails update'd to a current grails, except for spring-security-ui's translations seems to compile & work now. trying it on our jenkins on Mon.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at the [dependency report](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html):

```
grails dependency-report
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've seen that. However, the erroneous dependency does not show up in the HTML produced. Even grepping ~/.grails does not reveal the dependency.